# How to click on close button through code(without clicking manually) in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am looking for a functionality like:

```
self.ui.pushButton_connect2.click()
```

for the red cross button.

Comment: Why do not you call `close()`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use QTest, just find the position of the button. Just replace the `keypressEvent` with a method that your button connects to

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(Window,self).__init__(parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, QKeyEvent):
        if QKeyEvent.key() == Qt.Key_C:
            QTest.mousePress(self,Qt.LeftButton,Qt.KeyboardModifierMask,pos=QPoint(200,150))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos())
        super().mousePressEvent(event)



app = QApplication([])
w = Window()
w.show()
app.exit(app.exec_())`
```